# Having Problems Displaying followed users posts in Python Flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

So I have a problem with my project. I am trying to display the user's followings posts but nothing is displayed. I don't know what the problem is as no errors are being displayed. [This is what I am using to help me to query followed posts (page 158)](https://doc.lagout.org/programmation/python/Flask%20Web%20Development_%20Developing%20Web%20Applications%20with%20Python%20%5BGrinberg%202014-05-18%5D.pdf)

[This is where the posts should be displayed. This gives the user the option to show all posts or just followed posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9Bao.png)

Nothing is being displayed though.

Here is the User class where I am defining followed posts:

[The function followed_post() is supposed to display the users followed posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOKmG.png)

```
 @property
def followed_posts(self):
    return Post.query.join(Follow, Follow.followed_id == Post.user_id).filter(Follow.follower_id == self.id)
```

In my main routes i have ;

```
@main.route('/all')
@login_required
def show_all():
    resp = make_response(redirect(url_for('main.compscipost')))
    resp.set_cookie('showed_followed', '' , max_age = 
    30*24*60*60)
return resp

@main.route('/followed')
@login_required
def show_followed():
   resp = make_response(redirect(url_for('main.HomePage')))
   resp.set_cookie('showed_followed', '1', max_age = 30*24*60*60)
return resp
```

and also in the blueprint =' main'  routes.py,  the function for my homepage is :

```
@main.route('/')
@main.route('/home')
def HomePage():
  page = request.args.get('page', 1, type = int)
  showed_followed = False
  if current_user.is_authenticated:
    showed_followed = bool(request.cookies.get('showed_followed', ''))
  if showed_followed:
     query= current_user.followed_posts
  else: 
    query = Post.query
  pagination = 
query.order_by(Post.date_posted.desc()).paginate(page = page, 
per_page = 5, 
        error_out = False)
posts = pagination.items
return render_template("HomePage.html", posts =posts, 
showed_followed = showed_followed , 
    pagination = pagination)
```

Finally for my homepage.html which I think is where the main problem is :

[this is the homepage.html .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP5e0.png)

[This is a pastebin of the html](https://pastebin.com/J6ADWfxZ)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're just building a query in your `def followed_posts()` property.

You should end it with `.one()` or `.all()` or `first()`.

On a side note, if you're using SQLAlchemy take a look at hybrid properties. As regular Python properties will sometimes cause you problems when you're querying with instance and class attributes at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, in your `HomePage` endpoint you're setting `posts=pagination.items`, and in your HTML you're looping through `post.items` as well.

Try this in your HTML:

```
{% for post in posts %}
# ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you but the users image doesnt show up? so i scrapped the image part but what am i doing wrong

Comment: The user's image?